# MVVM - Add points to a map

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to use the MVVM pattern correctly.

So, with this example, I try to add some points to a map by using a MVVM model. What is the best way to do it?

**View:**

```
<map:Map Name="MyMap">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}"
                                    EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ConvertToPoint}"
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <map:MapLayer Name="MyLayer">

        </map:MapLayer>
    </map:Map>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand<Point> DoubleClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.DoubleClickCommand = new RelayCommand<Point>(CreatePoint);
    }

    private void CreatePoint(Point arg)
    {
        Ellipse pin = new Ellipse();
        pin.Width = 3;
        pin.Height = 3;
        pin.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

        Point point = arg;
        Location PointLocation = MyMap.ViewportPointToLocation(point);

        MyLayer.AddChild(pin, PointLocation);
    }
}
```

Both following rows are problematic because that uses the controls of the view:

> Location PointLocation = MyMap.ViewportPointToLocation(point);

and

> MyLayer.AddChild(pin, PointLocation);

Where do I have to write these ones? In the code behind of the view ?

Remark: I use a converter to get a point as argument of the function CreatePoint.

Comment: The MVVM purist would have no code behind in the view.  You only bind to you ViewModel which has a collection of points which is provided by your Model.

Comment: Your ViewModel does not have to know nothing about your view. That is MVVM breaking to. As @DanAndrews says, you have to create a map on the view model(or Model), and bind it to your view.

Comment: Instead of `EventToCommand` you can create attached behavior (using several attached properties). In code of that behavior you can then have access to everything: to double click event (subscribe to it), to map (pass it as attached property) and to ViewModel (DataContext of element or pass it as another attached property).

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a Messenger class to communicate between your View and ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the best approach would be to **bind** to the pushpin collection.

The **Bing Maps WPF Control** is not very forgiving when it comes to `Binding`. It isn't possible to directly bind to the map's `Children` property, therefore a different approach is needed.

Firstly, create a `UserControl` which contains your map, we can then use **Dependency Properties** to do an almost *proxy binding* to the `Children` collection.

```
<UserControl ...
         xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"">
<Grid>
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="Your API Key Here"
           x:Name="map"
           MouseDoubleClick="Map_DoubleClicked"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class BindableMap : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<Pushpin> Pins
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Pushpin>)GetValue(PinsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PinsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Pins.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PinsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Pins", typeof(ObservableCollection<Pushpin>), typeof(BindableMap),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPinsChanged)));

    private static void OnPinsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindableMap map = (BindableMap)d;

        //If the pin collection changes, then reset the map view.
        map.ClearMapPoints();
        map.SubscribeToCollectionChanged();
    }

    private void ClearMapPoints()
    {
        map.Children.Clear();
    }

    private void SubscribeToCollectionChanged()
    {
        if (Pins != null)
            Pins.CollectionChanged += Pins_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Pins_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove the old pushpins
        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (Pushpin pin in e.OldItems)
                map.Children.Remove(pin);

        //Add the new pushpins
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (Pushpin pin in e.NewItems)
                map.Children.Add(pin);
    }

    public BindableMap()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Pins = new ObservableCollection<Pushpin>();
    }

    private void Map_DoubleClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the current position of the mouse.
        Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(map);

        //Create the pin.
        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        pin.Location = map.ViewportPointToLocation(point);

        //Add the pin to the map.
        Pins.Add(pin);
    }
}
```

A thing to note here is that the `View`, in this case, the `UserControl` is handling the double click event. This doesn't necessarily need to be handled in the view model as we're going to use binding instead.

Here is a very simple view model:

```
public class BindableMapViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Pushpin> _Pushpins;

    public ObservableCollection<Pushpin> Pushpins
    {
        get { return _Pushpins; }
        set
        {
            _Pushpins = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    public BindableMapViewModel()
    {
        Pushpins = new ObservableCollection<Pushpin>();
    }
}
```

Now, all that's left is to use your `UserControl` in a parent `Window` and bind the `Pushpins` view model collection to the `Pins` **Dependency Property**. It'll look something like this:

```
<map:BindableMap Pins="{Binding Pushpins}"/>
```

And there you have it.

Comment: Interesting approach. But for the MVVM concept, an usercontrol must have a viewmodel associated or not ? I see a lot of people who create user controls (for example MasterView and DetailView) to use in a main window and bind it with a view model (for example MasterViewModel and DetailViewModel). What must we do or not ?

Comment: There's no law that dictates where and when you should create a view model. It really depends on the structure of your view and how you are using user controls. If it makes sense to create a new view model for the `UserControl`, such as a master-detail view, then do so. In the case of my example, my control does not have a view model at all, it instead binds it's `Pins` dependency property to the `Pushpins` view model property.